# NFA to DFA Diagram Conversion

Tags: equivalence-relations, automata, finite-state-machine

I've been tasked with converting an NFA to a DFA in diagram form.

The NFA is like so:
[NFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StpEt.png)

And my DFA:[Updated DFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLryb.png)

I have the nagging feeling that I'm missing something in the conversion regarding {1,2} and 'a' how the epsilon and move from the starting set of states to {2} or {3}. My textbook describes the general algorithm for the conversion, and that's how I arrived at the set of sets of active states that became nodes for the DFA, but it doesn't show how exactly a DFA from an NFA would look, so I'm looking for clarity. Is this DFA a correct representation of the NFA? And if not, where did I conceptually falter?

Edit: Updated the DFA diagram, there was one mistake when transcribing from paper. I still have the same questions!

Comment: It looks right to me, except  that state $3$ of the DFA doesn't have a transition on $b$.

Comment: Argh that seems so blindingly obvious now! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this to be the full and correct diagram. Thank you saulspatz for spotting the missing transition - the diagram below includes a transition from state 3 to itself when b is the input.

[Proper DFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i30y.png)